# Global variable declaration Error

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access the parseApacheLogLine variable but I am getting error in following code

```
logFile = "NASAlog.txt"
def parseLogs():
    global arseApacheLogLine
    parsed_logs=(sc
                .textFile(logFile)
                .map(parseApacheLogLine)
                .cache())

    access_logs = (parsed_logs
                .filter(lambda s: s[1] == 1)
                .map(lambda s: s[0])
                .cache())

    failed_logs = (parsed_logs
                .filter(lambda s: s[1] == 0)
                .map(lambda s: s[0]))
    failed_logs_count = failed_logs.count()
    if failed_logs_count > 0:
        print 'Number of invalid logline: %d' % failed_logs.count()
        for line in failed_logs.take(20):
            print 'Invalid logline: %s' % line

    print 'Read %d lines, successfully parsed %d lines, failed to parse %d lines' % (parsed_logs.count(), access_logs.count(), failed_logs.count())
    return parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs

parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs = parseLogs()
```

**Expected result: Configuration and Initial RDD Creation**

---

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        26     return parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs
>        27 
>   ---> 28 parsed_logs, access_logs, failed_logs = parseLogs()
>
> in parseLogs()
>         6     parsed_logs=(sc
>         7                 .textFile(logFile)
>   ----> 8                 .map(parseApacheLogLine)
>         9                 .cache())
>        10
>
> NameError: global name 'parseApacheLogLine' is not defined

Comment: `global arseApacheLogLine` <- that's probably your problem

Comment: This is one of the funniest syntax errors I've seen in a while.

Comment: If I delete that global variable its shows error message " No global variable is defined " @overactor

Comment: This code is part of learning in my program..! I developed it according to my requirements. @PencilVonRadiergummi